# How to install git hooks on "npm install"?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, githooks, npm-install

I'd like to install a `pre-commit` git hook (that lints the code) when someone installs `my-package`.

I tried to add a `postinstall` script:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "./scripts/install-git-hooks"
}
```

This works great. When someone runs `npm install`, they get the `pre-commit` hook installed.

However, if `another-package` depends on `my-package`, running `npm install` for `another-package` runs the `postinstall` script as well, which is undesired.

What's the cleanest way to avoid this undesired affect?

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You are asking about Y but to get answers that are going to be useful in the larger picture you should give us information about X. Why should your package install git hooks in the first place?

Comment: @Louis I'd like to enforce users to lint their code before they commit. I could guide users to run `npm run install-git-hooks` after they run `npm install`, but I'd like to automate this.

Comment: To be fair most npm packages that have some post-install routine you need to run on your project, have you manually do it. typings, jspm, jasmine... etc, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [ghooks](https://github.com/gtramontina/ghooks) npm module and add it as a dev-dependency. You can configure what to run before commit in your package.json like so:

```
[...]
"config": {
    "ghooks": {
        "pre-commit": "npm test"
    }
}
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Hacky, but might work for you.

The trick is to identify (within the script) if it is a sub-dependency or a root dependency for the NPM installation. Simply check if `../../package.json` exists. If so, it's a sub dependency and you should skip installing the hooks.

It should be noted that you are breaking any consistent installation rules, which is exactly against the spirit of the installation scripts. This is to install client-side hooks which cannot be trusted by any means, if you need the linting to be enforced, this should be done server side, where it can just reject code that doesn't comply.

Potentially this issue would be better solved like you mentioned, by having it as a custom install script, and just dealing with the additional communication overhead.